# Preventing suspend / sleep / hybernate of a server running LXDE on Ubuntu 18.04 after power up before login as a user

Tags: server, suspend, power-management, lxde

Anyone knows how to keep an Ubuntu 18.04 file server with LXDE from going to a low power mode after power up?

Problem description:
I usually access my home server remotely with teamviewer. If power goes down and comes back up the computer reboots. After a short time, it goes to a low power mode and I cannot access it remotely.
If I see this happens and quickly login as a user and then go away, the computer does not go to that low power mode.
(I think the low power mode is called "suspend" but I'm not sure, maybe is sleep. I don't believe is hybernate because the desktop shows up quickly when I press the computer's power button.)

Update on Nov. 19, 2019:
Two things I tried that did not fix the problem:

1. Disabling ACPI in the BIOS setup
2. Masking these four things: sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target (sudo systemctl mask [list of four], and then: sudo systemctl status [list of four] to confirm.)

Comment: Did you install Lubuntu 18.04 LTS or Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS and then add LXDE?  (or `lubuntu-desktop`).   Ubuntu Server doesn't suspend (you specifically mentioned server in the first line) so I'm wondering how you added LXDE onto your system? or if you did in fact start with Ubuntu Server (*you didn't mention Lubuntu at all*).  I'm currently unsure what your system actually is.

Comment: I installed the server edition 18.04.01 (amd64 in the file name). Then I added LXDE (using: sudo apt-get install lxde) because I couldn't get CrashPlan to backup that server without a graphical environment.